# AWS EC2 Sudden Spike in Read Request

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running in AWS using Apache2 Prefork.
Occasionally the server receives sudden spike in request that will cause us to run out of MaxRequestWorkers. Our server-status shows that more than half of it is serving the read request.

```
563 requests currently being processed, 48 idle workers
_RRRRKRRRRRR_RRCRWRWRRRRRR_W.RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRW_RRRRWR.RR_RRRRRR
WRRRRR_RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRWRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR.RRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRGRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRR_.RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR.RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRWRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR.___RRRRRRRR
RRRRRWR_RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRR.RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR_RRRRRKRRRRRKK___._RWRK_R_KR__R_.R.R_.R.__
RK_KR..._.._.__K_...R.RRR__W___WR.W_KK___R._RRR_._.._WRR_._R._._
._..............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
........................................
```

Looking at the request that uses up the worker. There's around 400 of Vhost of internal AWS IP address with the R request of OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0, we do not know where are these requests are coming from and how to stop them. Anyone can shed some light? Thanks!

```
78-28   3715997 0/0/76185   R   0.00    50  0   87938859    0.0 0.00    1848.67 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
79-28   3715998 0/0/72516   R   0.00    50  0   85997714    0.0 0.00    1750.79 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
80-28   3715999 0/0/72629   R   0.00    50  0   90070355    0.0 0.00    1720.41 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
81-28   3716000 0/0/70655   R   0.00    50  0   86603790    0.0 0.00    1640.44 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
82-28   3716001 0/0/66332   R   0.00    50  0   80164787    0.0 0.00    1566.97 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
83-28   3716002 0/0/64108   R   0.00    50  0   84202024    0.0 0.00    1577.83 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
84-28   3716003 0/0/63435   R   0.00    50  0   81187585    0.0 0.00    1526.87 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
85-28   3716004 0/0/59782   R   0.00    50  0   71954129    0.0 0.00    1453.71 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
86-28   3716005 0/0/59832   R   0.00    50  0   73754847    0.0 0.00    1394.68 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
87-28   3716006 0/0/56253   R   0.00    50  0   69634853    0.0 0.00    1298.93 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
88-28   3716007 0/0/56035   R   0.00    50  0   64290810    0.0 0.00    1392.39 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
89-28   3716008 0/0/54834   R   0.00    50  0   76210304    0.0 0.00    1335.42 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
90-28   3716009 0/0/53132   R   0.00    50  0   62505663    0.0 0.00    1230.73 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
91-28   3716010 0/0/52956   R   0.00    50  0   68731770    0.0 0.00    1256.98 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
92-28   3716011 0/0/50373   R   0.00    50  0   62309824    0.0 0.00    1188.31 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
93-28   3716016 0/0/52626   R   0.00    49  0   64762601    0.0 0.00    1248.75 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
94-28   3716017 0/0/48600   R   0.00    49  0   58527363    0.0 0.00    1140.82 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
95-28   3716018 0/0/44846   R   0.00    49  0   56541865    0.0 0.00    1000.34 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
96-28   3716019 0/0/45774   R   0.00    49  0   61303713    0.0 0.00    1052.58 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
97-28   3716020 0/0/44569   R   0.00    49  0   58099748    0.0 0.00    1045.96 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
98-28   3716021 0/0/43894   R   0.00    49  0   50976607    0.0 0.00    1032.84 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
99-28   3716022 0/0/42585   R   0.00    49  0   52307485    0.0 0.00    1049.96 ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
100-28  3716023 0/0/42589   R   0.00    49  0   61598189    0.0 0.00    976.25  ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
101-28  3716024 0/0/41245   R   0.00    49  0   52622569    0.0 0.00    912.63  ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
102-28  3716025 0/0/38232   R   0.00    49  0   411730724   0.0 0.00    952.59  ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
103-28  3716026 0/0/38976   R   0.00    49  0   53214297    0.0 0.00    921.58  ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
104-28  3716027 0/0/38987   R   0.00    49  0   49612947    0.0 0.00    916.66  ::1 http/1.1    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8 OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
```